# What Android distro can boot from USB stick in PC/Laptop?

Tags: usb, operating-system, android-x86

I have an old HP Pavilion dv2000 laptop with a busted hard drive. I want to put a compatible Android distro onto a USB thumb, plug this in to the laptop and boot into it and use it for casual www browsing.

Firstly, is this possible and if so, is LiveAndroid my only option?

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to use a mobile OS for desktop browsing?

Comment: I am interested in applying the OS - no matter the intended purpose - to other uses and applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.android-x86.org/

This is the only android distribution for Intel/AMD processors that I am aware of. It has little support, but is actively maintained. The latest version is a release candidate for Android 2.3. Obviously hardware support is hit and miss. For what it's worth it runs very well on my EEE PC.

You can install the ISO to a USB drive with Unetbootin, or use a drive imaging tool with the .img file.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your help Brendon. As it turns out, my computer is not supported but it was worth the effort.

Comment: It's not the only one - see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Remix OS** or **Phoenix OS** - both are Chinese distributions based on Android-x86. Here you can find [the differences between them](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134561/what-is-the-difference-between-remix-os-and-phoenix-os/).

There is also **Console OS**, but it seems not ready yet.