# What is the difference between Remix OS and Phoenix OS?

Tags: android-x86, remix-os

Both [Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/en/remixos-for-pc) and [Phoenix OS](http://www.phoenixos.com/download_x86) are free Chinese Android desktop distributions for x86_64 PC-s based on Android-x86. But how do they differ, excluding different themes?

Comment: You mean other than differences in GUI, are there differences at the core of them?

Comment: @Firelord This is what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a community wiki, you can extend it.

---

According to [Phoenix Studio forum](http://bbs.phoenixstudio.org/read.php?tid=1986&fid=12) ([translation](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?from=&to=en&a=http%3A%2F%2Fbbs.phoenixstudio.org%2Fread.php%3Ftid%3D1986%26fid%3D12)) and other sources:

- both are based on Android 5.1 Lollipop,
- both support Legacy BIOS and UEFI boot methods, but sometimes Phoenix OS Legacy mode does not boot, unlike UEFI,
- Remix OS lacks adjustable windows and some of them can only be maximized or minimized,
- Remix OS requires USB 3.0, Phoenix OS only USB 2.0,
- Phoenix OS boots faster,
- Phoenix OS fluency and functionality are better than the Remix OS,
- Phoenix OS 1.0 is 370MB, Remix OS 2.0 is 689 MB, both zipped.

Remix OS 2.0 Launcher:

[image: Remix OS 2.0 Launcher]

Phoenix OS 1.0 Launcher:

[image: Phoenix OS 1.0 Launcher]

Images source: Softpedia

Video comparison: http://youtu.be/E6BNcXRyOr4

Comment: looking at their forum Phoenix OS has a lot of spam issues http://bbs.phoenixstudio.org/en/forumdisplay.php?fid=4

Comment: @LiamWilliam How does it affect the OS itself?

Comment: I wouldn't think it isn't supported very well considering how spam ridden the site is.  They don't necessarily effect each other but I wouldn't say its irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Add to the above answer; from what I found while testing both OSes:-

- Phoenix OS is now x86 only platform, while Remix is x86/Arm
- Phoenix OS supports window transparency.
- File manager in Phoenix OS makes more sense in use.
- Settings panel of Phoenix OS is more well-organised.
- Phoenix OS still lacks of Ethernet support. (major drawback).
- Phoenix OS doesn't support 2nd screen output (on laptops), while Remix can mirror and allows the main screen to be turned off via laptop's function key.
- Applications running in full-screen (most 3D games) work properly in Remix OS, while those running on Phoenix OS tend to leave space at the bottom (what likely the size of hidden status bar+title bar) and miscalculate the mouse position in Y-axis (title bar height above the actual picture on screen).

My personal verdict so far:-

- If you just need the desktop oriented Android and play games less,
  choose Phoenix OS.
- If you care more for Android 3D games, choose Remix OS.

Comment: you should (maybe?) add those also in the top post, which is community wiki for that purpose ? (I won't, as I don't have first-hand experience on those 2 OSes)

Answer (score 1):

I can add to the above:

- In PhoenixOS clicking "X" in the top window bar doesn't kill the app; thanks to that, apps can run in background without icon being visible in the bottom taskbar (like in Remix)
- PhoenixOS works with floating windows just fine, no matter of app window size. RemixOS fails at this quite much - works only for some apps and only in fullscreen mode
- PhoenixOS has already built-in brightness control availible in Display options, slider on the notification area and via function keys on keyboard; RemixOS has this hidden, but it works with function keys
- RemixOS since ver .205 lags significantly due to badly designed use of android.process.media - Media Storage (media scanner); PhoenixOS still has a media scanner, but it works just fine without overusing CPU/storage resources. Moreover, RemixOS won't respect "pm hide android.process.media" command. It won't disable the lagging app. What's interesting, in PhoenixOS this command is useless too, but in Phoenix, u can Disable any app you want in settings, in Remix you don't.
- RemixOS has better performance in 3D like @Yoswin Chance reported, but  PhoenixOS starts and runs all other apps way better then Remix; it can easily compete with Windows 8.1 on my Asus T100TA (2GB RAM, Atom Z3740)
- RemixOS mounts all drives live with no 3rd party apps; PhoenixOS opposite
  **- To make things clear: PhoenixOS will output video to an external monitor just fine, but it will display it only on the external device and only if you plug it in before booting**

For now, I fully agree with @Yoswin Chance.

- PhoenixOS has far better windows system, start menu and notification area making the system more friendly and intuitive; feels much more complete then the RemixOS
- RemixOS right now is only better at games and overall feels like more like an alpha build

**UPDATE:**
I've just tested RemixOS 32bit on my Asus T100TA (32bit UEFI) and it's super fast, but of course I had to get rid of android.process.media app in order to get the performance reliable.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest update Phoenix OS also supports ethernet connections. I have been using both OSes but Phoenix OS is faster in booting and running apps, so I prefer Phoenix OS to Remix OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful and detailed comparison of Phoenix, Remix, and plain Android-x86 from August 2016 here:
http://apcmag.com/371021.htm/

Comment: It would help if you could edit your answer and add relevant quotes from the linked article, in case the web page goes down (a.k.a. link rot.)

Comment: @Chahk Here is the [archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20161016113433/http://apcmag.com/371021.htm/).